# What does "on the fly" in a DBMS mean when performing query optimization?

Tags: query-optimization, database

I'm studying about optimizers and plans for a DBMS.

It says somewhere that "selections/projections are processed **on the fly**"

I can't understand what "on the fly" means.

Is it related to "pipelining" or "materilization" in a DBMS?

thanks

Comment: Found it finally on the web: "On-the-fly:  The result of one operator is pipelined to another operator without creating a temporary table to hold  intermediate result, called  on-the-fly."

Comment: What's up with the down votes?

Comment: @programmer: I think the convention to answering your own question is to type it in as an answer (not a comment) and accept it. Then it doesn't show up as unanswered.